# accessing the json data from axios call in vue

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I setup a fake mocke server in postman to get som test data for my vue applikation. This is what i am getting from the server:

[image]

I want to access the data information but i am having hard time doing so. This is the code that i am using:

```
<template>
  <div class="admin">
    <h1>This is admin page area</h1>

    <JsonEditor :objData="config" v-model="config" ></JsonEditor>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import{getConfig} from "../utils/network";

import Vue from 'vue'
import JsonEditor from 'vue-json-edit'

Vue.use(JsonEditor)

export default{

  data: function () {
    return {
      config:{}
    }
  },
  created:function(){
    getConfig()
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
              this.config = response;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried doing `response.data` but did not work. I am feeding this to the json editor but it is currently not being able to show the json. Its empty. This is my network call code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

const getConfig = () =>{
    return Vue.axios.get('https://8db51a11-752e-4d64-b237-8195055fbf26.mock.pstmn.io')
};

//Export getConfig so other classes can use it
export{
  getConfig
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: you should use `async/await`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try providing a then statement:

```
const getConfig = () =>{
    Vue.axios.get('https://8db51a11-752e-4d64-b237-8195055fbf26.mock.pstmn.io').then(response => {
return response.data});
};
```